# Can "could not" be replaced by "can not"?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

In the following quote:

> This means that one **could not** predict with confidence whether a person
> who scored high on the trait of generosity would behave in a generous
> manner in a given situation.

Can the "could not" be replaced by "can not"? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

Context determines whether "could not" is replaceable with "can not". The modal verb *could* is preferred to formulate more formal and polite requests, the meaning in both versions is the same.

- Could I have a glass of water?
- Can I have a glass of water?

In English when we talk about ABILITY in the PRESENT, we use *can*, *can not*, or *cannot*. The construction *be able to* would also be possible here.

> Machines **cannot** predict a person's IQ based on their physical appearance.

> Machines **are not able to** predict a person's IQ based on their physical appearance.

In the OP's example, the situation appears to refer to an ABILITY in the PAST (without the actual source there is no way to be certain). The author seems to claim that in the past it was difficult to know with reliability whether someone who **scored high** on the trait of generosity **would behave** generously in a specific situation.

> This means that one **could not predict** with confidence.

If *could not* is replaced with *can not*, the implication is the situation has since changed. It is now possible to predict with greater confidence using better tests.

> This means that one **can not** predict with confidence whether a person who scored high on the trait of generosity would behave in a generous manner in a given situation.